# The argument type 'XFile?' can't be assigned to the parameter type

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
  late XFile?  _file;
      String status = '';
      late String base64Image;
      late File tmpFile;
      String errMessage = 'Error Uploading Image';

Widget showImage() {
return FutureBuilder<File>(
future: _file,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
```

---

how :(?

Comment: `_file` is not a future, what are you trying to do?

Comment: ı have       _file  = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); but how to ...................future: _file, ..........this is giving error??

Comment: Because it is not a future, can you describe more what exactly the ux you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use FutureBuilder, you must change your _file to Future type, like this :

```
Future<XFile?>  _file;


_file =_picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);  // remove await
```

then you can return your FutureBuilder like you wish